# cambiar select option a button personalizado enviando id y value

Tags: javascript, html, css, formularios

Tengo un js que usa #name dentro y el script case "codehere", pero recopila su información de un formulario, quiero reemplazarlo con un botón personalizado que envía la misma información que la opción de selección.

```
<!--this is inside a form html-->
<select name="name" id="name">
<option value="codehere1234">optionname1</option>   
<option value="codehere4567">optionname</option>                  
<select>
<!-- i want to send same info with a custom button-->
<div class="button">
<button >optioname1</button>
</div>
<div class="button">
<button >optioname2</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var id;
      function LoadQr() {
        $("#pricespace").show();
        var price= 140;

         switch ($("#name").val()) {
          case "codehere1234":
            price = 26.0;
            break;
          case "codehere4567":
            price = 70.0;
            break;
             default:
```

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow EN ESPAÑOL, por favor, traduce tu pregunta y no olvides pasarte por [ask] - [tour]

Comment: Si no traduces la pregunta, va a terminar cerrada y no aceptará respuestas. Por favor, ve a [edit] y tradúcela. :)

Comment: Traducido de inglés código js